# How to install PyQt4 to Python 2.7 in Centos 6?

Tags: python, pyqt4, centos6

I managed to install PyQt4 but it install under Python 2.6. How do I get it installed under Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it via python2.7 pip install pyqt4